# how to echo data as it in table view

Tags: php

i have this code that get data from db but it show only one row in table , another row it will show outside table

i want all data show in table

! [this is my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mrtB.png)

and this is my code for connect to database

```
<?
session_start();
require('../config.php');
require('../data.php');
require('../fungsi.php');
functionUserLock();
$userStatus=$r["suspend"];
functionUserBlocked($userStatus);
include "head.php";
?>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">

      <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <? echo $phname ; ?> History</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">

              <thead>
                <tr>

                  <th>
                    <center>Id Trx</center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center>Date</center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center>Amount</center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center>Pair</center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center>Not Pair</center>
                  </th>

                  <th>
                    <center>Available for
                      <? echo $skgh; ?>
                    </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center>Stats</center>
                  </th>
                  <th colspan="2">
                    <center>Option</center>
                  </th>

                </tr>

              </thead>
              <br>
              <tbody>
```

and this is part of mycode ,it display in table but it display only one row , and another row is out of table

```
<?
$lole=$_COOKIE["username"];
$tabla = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_ph where username='$lole'  and status!='ditahan' ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1000000"); 
while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($tabla)) { 
$yereka=$registro["verify"];
$perek=$registro["username"];
$pereka=$registro["id"];
$ferpax=$registro["id"];
$ferpaxd=$registro["username"];



$wedokan=$derekasu * $derekasur;


 $hari = date("H");
  $token=md5($frozenIdTrx.$hari);
            echo "
<tr>

<td>". $registro["idtrx"] ."</td>
<td>". date("d M Y H:i:s A",$registro["date"]) ."</td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($registro["paket"]) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($derekc) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($registro["saldo"]) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($foolas) ." </td>
<td>". $mystats ."</td>
<td><div data-target=\"#DETAIL$ferpax\" data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-xs\" style=\"float:center;\"><center>DETAIL</center></div>
</td>
</tr>

";
?>

 
</tbody>


</table>
   
      


<div id="DETAIL<? echo $registro["id"]; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-responsive-label" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</button>
                                <h4 id="modal-responsive-label" class="modal-title">Detail Transactions</h4></div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

              
<? echo showPhOrderMemberKananModal($ferpaxd,$ferpax); ?> <br>
<? echo showPhOrderMemberKananModalList($ferpaxd,$ferpax); ?>


 <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<?
}
?>
<?
include "foot.php";
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable with proper indentation. It is really hard to follow like this.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell but it looks like you aren't closing your loop in the right place.

Also, Have you checked your raw query results to make sure you have more than one row returned?

```
    <?
$lole=$_COOKIE["username"];
$tabla = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_ph where username='$lole'  and status!='ditahan' ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1000000"); 
while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($tabla)) { 
$yereka=$registro["verify"];
$perek=$registro["username"];
$pereka=$registro["id"];
$ferpax=$registro["id"];
$ferpaxd=$registro["username"];



$wedokan=$derekasu * $derekasur;


 $hari = date("H");
  $token=md5($frozenIdTrx.$hari);
            echo "
<tr>

<td>". $registro["idtrx"] ."</td>
<td>". date("d M Y H:i:s A",$registro["date"]) ."</td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($registro["paket"]) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($derekc) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($registro["saldo"]) ." </td>
<td>$matauang ". number_format($foolas) ." </td>
<td>". $mystats ."</td>
<td><div data-target=\"#DETAIL$ferpax\" data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-xs\" style=\"float:center;\"><center>DETAIL</center></div>
</td>
</tr>

";

} // **<------- You need to close the loop here maybe....**
?>

 
</tbody>


</table>
   
      


<div id="DETAIL<? echo $registro["id"]; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-responsive-label" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</button>
                                <h4 id="modal-responsive-label" class="modal-title">Detail Transactions</h4></div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

              
<? echo showPhOrderMemberKananModal($ferpaxd,$ferpax); ?> <br>
<? echo showPhOrderMemberKananModalList($ferpaxd,$ferpax); ?>


 <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<?
} **// then remove this one i think**
?>
```